# Dynamic program for knapsack in $O(W)$ space?

Tags: knapsack, dynamic-programming

A familiar [dynamic programming algorithm for the binary knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#0-1_knapsack_problem)
$$
\begin{align}
\text{maximize}\quad & v \cdot x \\
\text{subject to} \quad & w \cdot x \leq W \\
\quad&x_i \text{ binary}
\end{align}
$$

is as follows: Let $m[i, w]$ denote the highest utility achievable in a knapsack that uses only the first $i$ items and has capacity $w$. Then the optimal objective value is $m[n, W]$ which can be computed using the following recursion relation:

$$
\begin{align}
m[0, w] &= 0 \\
m[i, w] &= \begin{cases}
m[i-1, w], \quad &w_i > W \\
\min\lbrace m[i-1, w], m[i-1, w - w_i] + v_i\rbrace, \quad& w_i \leq W
\end{cases}
\end{align}
$$
A standard way to implement this algorithm is to fill an $n \times W$ array with the $m[i, w]$-values, then determine the optimal solution by iterating backwards from $m[n, W]$ by observing that $x_i = 1$ if and only if $m[i, w] > m[i-1, w]$.

As Wikipedia notes (emphasis mine),

> This solution will therefore run in $O(nW)$ time and $O(nW)$ space. **(If we only need the value $m[n,W]$, we can modify the code so that the amount of memory required is $O(W)$ which stores the recent two lines of the array `m`.)**

Wikipedia doesn't cite any sources here, and I am curious if this is truly the state of the art. Suppose that I *do* want the $x$-vector and not just the objective value. **Is $O(nW)$-space the best we can do?**

- ... or is there a clever way to organize the two-line table that keeps track of whether or not each $x_i = 1$ and uses $O(W)$-space after all?
- ... or is there a way to prove that the solution cannot use less than $O(nW)$-space unless (for example) P = NP?

---

N.B. This question is *exclusively* concerned with the implementation of the item-weight-based dynamic program given above. I know that there are other algorithms for the knapsack problem with lighter space requirements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a recursive scheme which makes it possible to retrieve the optimal solution with an $O(n + W)$ memory. It is described in Section 3.3 of the book ["Knapsack Problems" (Kellerer et al., 2004)](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-540-24777-7)

In case you're interested, I've done a C++ implementation [here](https://github.com/fontanf/knapsacksolver/blob/master/knapsacksolver/algorithms/bellman.cpp#L542), and a comparison between the different ways to retrieve the optimal solution [here](https://github.com/fontanf/knapsacksolver#dynamic-programming-cost-of-retrieving-an-optimal-solution)

Comment: Think it should be $O(n + W)$.

Comment: I updated the answer, but I'm not sure that it really requires $O(n)$ space. The number of items in the solution is smaller than $W$. $O(n)$ space is required to store the instance, $O(\log n)$ is required to store the recursive call stack, but I don't see where $O(n)$ space is required inside the algorithm itself.

Comment: I think it at least depends on whether you require the output vector to be encoded as a full vector, which gives you $O(n)$ for the construction of the output, or whether you allow it to be encoded as a sparse vector. In the latter case it seems to make sense to assume $W \geq m \geq n$ with $m$ the number of items in the output, as $W=m$ kind of implies all items use capacity $1$. If you allow items that do not consume $0$ capacity the story would be a bit different, but you could easily get rid of those edge cases by appropiate preprocessing/postprocessing.